# bower EACCES error, permision denied

Tags: node.js, twitter-bootstrap-3, bower

I've run ito this problem, while installing bootstrap. Any suggestions?

```
bower not-cached    https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap.git#*
bower resolve       https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap.git#*
bower checkout      bootstrap#v3.3.6
**bower EACCES        EACCES: permission denied, open '/Users/criticus/.cache/bower/packages/478ab1d28ba78f550601bf536eea62f5-3.3.6.lock'**
```

Stack trace:

```
Error: EACCES: permission denied, open '/Users/criticus/.cache/bower/packages/478ab1d28ba78f550601bf536eea62f5-3.3.6.lock'
    at Error (native)
```

Console trace:

```
Error
    at StandardRenderer.error (/Users/criticus/NPM/lib/node_modules/bower/lib/renderers/StandardRenderer.js:81:37)
    at Logger.<anonymous> (/Users/criticus/NPM/lib/node_modules/bower/lib/bin/bower.js:110:26)
    at emitOne (events.js:77:13)
    at Logger.emit (events.js:169:7)
    at Logger.emit (/Users/criticus/NPM/lib/node_modules/bower/lib/node_modules/bower-logger/lib/Logger.js:29:39)
    at /Users/criticus/NPM/lib/node_modules/bower/lib/commands/index.js:48:20
    at _rejected (/Users/criticus/NPM/lib/node_modules/bower/lib/node_modules/q/q.js:844:24)
    at /Users/criticus/NPM/lib/node_modules/bower/lib/node_modules/q/q.js:870:30
    at Promise.when (/Users/criticus/NPM/lib/node_modules/bower/lib/node_modules/q/q.js:1122:31)
    at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (/Users/criticus/NPM/lib/node_modules/bower/lib/node_modules/q/q.js:788:41)
System info:
Bower version: 1.7.9
Node version: 4.4.7
OS: Darwin 15.5.0 x64
```

I've tried

```
sudo bower install --allow-root
sudo chown -R $USER:$GROUP ~/.npm
sudo chown -R $USER:$GROUP ~/.config
```

and nothing of these helped.

Comment: did you try deleting '~/.cache/bower' ?

Comment: Just tried it! It helped, thanks a lot!!

Comment: I also went to cache folders and removed all the file manually.

Comment: I posted it as an answer so you can close the thread. Thanks for the feedback. Could you please validate it as a valid answer, or complete if it wasn't complete ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try deleting your bower cache:

```
sudo rm -r ~/.cache/bower
```

Comment: this fixed my issue :)